# Why the slick carrousel does not align in the center?

Tags: jquery, css, divi

I have used the slick slider code applyed to a Supreme before/after image slider, but i cant for some reason align it in the center of the page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    swipe: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0px',
    responsive: \[{
        breakpoint: 980,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }\
    ]
  });

  function centerCarousel() {
    var carousel = jQuery('.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider');
    var slideWidth = carousel.find('.slick-slide').width();
    var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var slideMargin = (windowWidth - slideWidth) / 2;
    carousel.css('margin-left', -slideMargin);
  }

});
```

```css
.slick-slider {
  \-webkit-user-select: none;
  \-moz-user-select: none;
  \-ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  \-webkit-touch-callout: none;
  \-khtml-user-select: none;
  ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  \-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  margin-right: -23px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  draggable: false
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: '';
}

.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  align-items: center
}

.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-arrow,
.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-arrow:hover,
.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-arrow:focus {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  background: #2b4a70;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 100;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
}

.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-prev {
  left: -50px;
}

.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-next {
  right: -50px;
}

.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-arrow:before {
  font-family: ETmodules;
  color: #000;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 46px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #e5e2da;
  text-align: center;
}

.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-arrow:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-prev:before {
  content: '\\34';
}

.divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-next:before {
  content: '\\35';
}

.entry-content ul.slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-dots li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #4a80c2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background-color: #2b4a70;
}

@media(max-width: 980px) {
  .divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-prev {
    left: -32px;
  }
  .divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-next {
    right: -30px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 499px) {
  .divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-prev {
    left: -26px;
  }
  .divilife-3-col-feature-blurb-slider .slick-next {
    right: -24px;
  }
}
```

This is how it looks now:

This is how it looks:
[image: current output screenshot]
Backend DIVI :
[image: Backend DIVI]

the site is being hosted at (https://royal.nhcom.com.br)

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thank You!!